# Assigning values of angular momentum transfer

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

How do the shapes of the experimentally measured differential scattering or transfer cross sections help in assigning reliable angular momentum transfer values?

Comment: Hello. Maybe you could post some things more in your question to make it clearer. Explain a bit what you are asking if you have the time. Thank you.

Comment: if we know the shape of the angular distribution of differential scattering or transfer cross sections, could we determine the angular momentum momentum transferred in that process of scattering/transfer?